# IPhone 5 optimize old xib

Tags: ios, xcode, optimization, screen, iphone-5

This is my problem: I need instructions on how to fix the 3.5 inch xib for the 4 inch screen. I have already loaded the Default-568 img so I no longer have the letterbox layout.

I have the traditoinal 3.5 inch scren XIB and everything is perfect.

But when we turn to the 4 inch screen there is a large space to be filled and if I rearrange the XIB file for the iphone 5 screen when I turn to the 3.5 screen I can't see the button. Does it makes sense? Also I want to support versions prior to ios 6.

What I need is a fix or code or anything for the IPhone larger screen to be distributed proportionally.I have been reading that a solution could be duplicating the original xib file and arrange myself duplicated file in a 4 inch layout but I could´t figure out how to let the IPhone make the decision of opening one of the two xib files existing.

I have been given this piece of code but I still do not know where to paste it. I tried in the viewDidLoad but nothing;

```
if(thisDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    NSLog(@"Ipad ");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Iphone %f ",[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) {
        //this is iphone 5 xib
        viewName=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"ViewControllerIphone5"];
    } else {
        // this is iphone 4 xib
        viewName=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"ViewController"];
    }
}
```

I don´t know where to put that code; I know it is in the implementation file but I don't know where.I don't want autoresizing masks

Please, I´ll be glad if you could help me with this problem. I need careful instructions as I don´t have a lot of knowledge in the topic.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 4 options

1-) using a seperate xib file for 4'' screen, and in applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions method deciding which xib to load depending on mainScreen height.

2-) using auto layout ( only ios 6 + )

3-) using struts and springs

4-) calling a method only on 4'' devices, and setting view's frames and positions for 4'' display manually in that method

Comment: Thank you for your response and the range of options you provided me with. If anything bad happens I´ll answer back. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have separate nibs for this case. Use your normal 3.5 inch layout and use auto layout or springs and struts (under the dimensions tab for each object) to make the view resize correctly.

Check the Apple docs on Auto Layout and Springs and Struts for more info.

Comment: I want to support iOS 5 also so using auto layout will not allow me to do so.

Comment: @PeacetoYou springs and struts it is then?

Comment: Yep. Use Springs and Struts.